# Initializing a vector to a list of integers

Tags: c++, vector, graph, constructor

To represent a Graph in adjacency-list style, I'm using a vector containing pointers to a list of adjacent.

```
class Graph
{
public:
Graph(int V)
{
    vector<list<int> *> vertices(V);
}
// Member functions for Graph class
void addEdge();
void print();
void type(string);
 private:
vector<list<int> *> vertices;
};
```

Getting the number of vertices from the user in main function-> passing it to the constructor, it all works, meaning the vector is being initialized of the desired size! But right after the program comes back from the header file to the main function, Things change! as in tracing the value of vertices: the size is somehow being reset somewhere that I don' know of!!!

```
int size;
cout << "Enter the number of vertices in the Graph: ";
cin >> size;
Graph g(size);
```

Immona need help with this, what could possibly go wrong?!

Comment: Your constructor is not doing what you think it is (think local variables). Also, why do you need the vector to hold pointers?

Comment: holding pointers is for adjacency-list representation of graph. that's why I need the vector to hold pointers to a list of adjacent vertices. Is that a wrong approach? or less efficient?

Comment: I can see no reason why you want to hold pointers. If there is no reason, then it is the wrong approach because it brings in a lot of complexity.

Comment: That's right! made the life a lot harder at that point! what could be the right way to do that then?

Comment: Probably just `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: @mehdix_ - Maybe you should explain why `std::vector<std::list<int>>` will not work for you.  My rule of thumb is that if you're using pointers, you better have a good explanation as to why the value-based approach won't work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -This is because to properly implement the adjacency-list representation of a Graph, or at least the right way of my understanding of graph adjacency-list representation.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a temporary vector (local variable) in your constructor :

```
Graph(int V)
{
    vector<list<int> *> vertices(V);
}
```

You need to initialize your member variable instead :

```
Graph(int V) : vertices(V) {}
```

Also, I would suggest using `std::unique_ptr<list<int>>` instead of raw pointers if you really need to use pointers, else simply store plain `std::list<int>`.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't compiler yell about shadowing a member with a local variable in the 1st case? I am surprised it would let slip something like that tbh.

Comment: Compiling with mingw32 v4.8.2 and no flags, no warning is issued. Compiling with `-W -Wall` only indicates that the variable is unused.

Comment: The next thing is addEdge() function should be adding in a right position in the vector and and the end of list that index pointing to; Any idea how would that be?

Comment: How do you define _the right position_ ? Also, as this is another question, you should consider closing this one by accepting the answer that helped you and opening another one.

Comment: That if the user wants to add at the first index; which is the 0'th index in the vector, the function will push back to the list that the containing pointer is pointing to. something like: vertices[0].push_back(a list of adjacent)!

Comment: You know what the user needs to provide, so write your prototype accordingly : something like `void addEdge (size_t index, std::list<int> const & adjacents);`.